# Joint PDF, Independence of Random variables

Tags: probability, random-variable, independence, variable

I can't understand some steps in this example, my question is about the encircled steps in red.
How to find these values ($x_1, x_2, x_{11}, x_{21}, x_{22} $), and what is its relation with that of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$
Please illustrate steps of finding what to do, to find these values.

[image]

Comment: You only need to prove $X_1+X_2$ is independent from $X_1-X_2$.

Comment: Isn't this just a special case of the famous theorem that $\bar{X}$ and $S^2$ are independent for the normal population?

Comment: It's also a special case of the theorem that uncorrelated bivariate Normal random variables are independent. It's just about as easy to prove that theorem as it is to do the calculations in a special case like this one, because it amounts to re-expressing the log probability density in terms of the new variables, which is just elementary algebra of quadratic forms.

Comment: @Zhanxiong 
No, this is a problem from ***Change of Variable technique*** in probability.